# How to integrate sandbox in coinbase/coinbase php library..?

Tags: php, bitcoin, coinbase-api

I have setup coinbase/coinbase library, and it will setup successfully and working, but when I start work with sandbox it'll give me error.

Suppose I have added my apikey,api-secretekey and sandbox url like below :

```
   $configuration = Configuration::apiKey($apiKey,$apiSecret);
   $configuration->setApiUrl(Configuration::SANDBOX_API_URL);
   $client = Client::create($configuration);
```

It return exception error like below :

```
Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException' with message ' in D:\wamp\www\open_digy-pay\trunk\vendor\coinbase\coinbase\src\Exception\HttpException.php on line 37
```

When I remove sandbox url line from code it'll work fine but without sandbox How could I test.

Any one having idea why it'll give me error like below?

[image]

Comment: Without sandbox it's use Live Account APIs if you remove SandboxURL complete line. then you have to use Live APIs key

Comment: @M Arfan : That I understand but Now problem is I think with url is with ssl certified is it so..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have API Keys Error 
**1:** Login to Coinbase Sandbox account 
**2:** Setting -> API Access
**3:** Create +New API Key for Sandbox Account

Now Try with sandbox keys

```
$apiKey = "***************";
$apiSecret = "*******************************";
$configuration = Configuration::apiKey($apiKey, $apiSecret);
$configuration->setApiUrl(Configuration::SANDBOX_API_URL);
$client = Client::create($configuration);
```

It's work for me Thanks

Comment: @M Arfan : apikey and apisecret key both should be from sandbox..?

Comment: One more question regarding sandbox integration my url should be https..?

Comment: Yes both from sandbox and It's not necessary URL in https

Comment: @M Arfan : I have setup key & secret key but it'll give me error..[Can you check my question I have updated my question with error]